# Selecting 3 random div's

Tags: php

I want the content section to displays three featured products available in the store out of a list of 10 products( so there will be 10 DIV's like the 1 div ). I have tried a few different things but I can't seem to get this to work. I would like to only use one file for this so my PHP will be with my html and such. I am very new to PHP so have no clue where to start.

```
    <div class="main_content">
      <div id="1">
        <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_kv1azAjQ8gY/TMb35lxK3tI/AAAAAAAABb8/62UYmGI4_MU/s1600/pork-schnitzel-done.jpg">
        <p>Pork Schnitzel  $ 5.50</p>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You can try with shuffle, array_chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to obtain a random number, and store it in a variable.

```
<?php 
$randomnum = rand(1, 10);
```

Then, we will do a switch statement to determine which div to output based on which condition.

```
switch ($randomnum) {
case 1:
echo "<div>whatever you want here</div>";
break;
case 2:
echo "<div>whatever you want here</div>";
break;
}
```

And just just do all the cases up to 10.